# I am getting an error of `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` while working with EJB

Tags: java, ejb

I am getting an error of `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` while working with **EJB**.

**Tools and Technologies:**

Eclipse Kepler

EJB 3.0

Oracle 11g

Jboss 7.1.0

---

I have came across some solutions that adding a ojdbc14.jar/ojdbc6.jar will work.

I have added jar files to the classpath but it is still giving the same exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException".

Jboss server log is as given below:

---

```
17:27:07,275 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver from [Module "deployment.NewEJB.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]

17:27:07,278 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)

17:27:07,279 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)

17:27:07,281 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)

17:27:07,282 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)

17:27:07,284 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)

17:27:07,286 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

17:27:07,287 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)

17:27:07,289 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at com.session.LibraryPersistentBean.getList(LibraryPersistentBean.java:39)

17:27:07,291 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

17:27:07,293 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

17:27:07,295 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

17:27:07,298 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

17:27:07,300 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72)

17:27:07,304 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

17:27:07,307 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)

17:27:07,311 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36)

17:27:07,313 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

17:27:07,314 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)

17:27:07,316 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

17:27:07,317 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)

17:27:07,319 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

17:27:07,320 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)

17:27:07,322 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)

17:27:07,324 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

17:27:07,327 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)

17:27:07,330 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

17:27:07,333 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228)

17:27:07,336 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304)

17:27:07,338 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190)

17:27:07,340 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

17:27:07,342 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropogatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropogatingInterceptor.java:80)

17:27:07,344 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

17:27:07,345 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)

17:27:07,347 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

17:27:07,349 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)

17:27:07,350 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

17:27:07,353 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)

17:27:07,355 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

17:27:07,357 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)

17:27:07,359 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

17:27:07,361 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)

17:27:07,364 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165)

17:27:07,365 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.processInvocation(LocalEjbReceiver.java:179)

17:27:07,367 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:173)

17:27:07,369 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:43)

17:27:07,371 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:175)

17:27:07,372 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:92)

17:27:07,374 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:175)

17:27:07,375 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:136)

17:27:07,377 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:121)

17:27:07,379 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:104)

17:27:07,380 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.getList(Unknown Source)

17:27:07,381 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at com.login.action.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:48)

17:27:07,383 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)

17:27:07,384 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)

17:27:07,386 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)

17:27:07,387 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)

17:27:07,388 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)

17:27:07,390 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)

17:27:07,391 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)

17:27:07,393 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)

17:27:07,394 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)

17:27:07,395 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)

17:27:07,398 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

17:27:07,400 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)

17:27:07,402 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)

17:27:07,404 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)

17:27:07,405 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)

17:27:07,407 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154)

17:27:07,410 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)

17:27:07,416 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

17:27:07,418 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

17:27:07,419 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)

17:27:07,421 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)

17:27:07,424 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)

17:27:07,427 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)

17:27:07,430 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8081-1)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

---

This is my code:

```
package com.session;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import com.entity.Book;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class LibraryPersistentBean
 */
@Stateless
public class LibraryPersistentBean implements LibraryPersistentBeanRemote {

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public LibraryPersistentBean() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public List<Book> getList() {
        Connection con = null;
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
        String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";

        String userName = "NL";
        String password = "NL";
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
        try {

             Class.forName(driver);
             con = DriverManager.getConnection(url , userName, password);

             Statement st = con.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM LOGIN");

             Book book;
             while (rs.next()) {
                book = new Book();
                book.setId(rs.getInt(1));                 
                book.setUsername(rs.getString(2));
                books.add(book);
             }
          } catch (SQLException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
          }
          return books;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: make sure the ojdbc14.jar/ojdbc6.jar file is in your WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: Yeah I already said that I have added those jar files.

Comment: Hey Developers... Please focus on the first line of Jboss server log.

Comment: add the full stack trace to your question

Comment: Please see first and then comment. I have added the full stack trace.

Comment: did you add the driver library to the jboss server modules?

Comment: How to add driver library? Can u give me some info. on that...

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new module, for your Oracle datasource, into your JBoss 7.1.0. application server.

In order to do that, you need to do the following:

1. Create a new folder structure: <JBOSS_HOME>/modules/**com/oracle/db/main**
2. Copy your OJDBC JAR into your newly created directory mentioned above
3. Create a file named *module.xml*, in the directory mentioned in **1.**:

   ```
   <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.oracle.db">
       <resources>
           <resource-root path="ojdbc.jar"/>
       </resources>
       <dependencies>
           <module name="javax.api"/>
           <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
       </dependencies>
   </module>
   ```
4. Modify your *standalone.xml* file in order to accommodate the newly created module:

   ```
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.2">
       <datasources>
       (...)
       </datasources>
       <drivers>
           <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.db">
               <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
           </driver>
       </drivers>
   </subsystem>
   ```
5. Finally, you just need to configure your datasource according to your needs.

---

Further information can be found in the following links:

- [Create a module for Oracle datasource in JBoss 7.1.1.Final](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/CreateAModuleForOracleDatasourceInJBoss711Final)
- [Installing Oracle JDBC Driver on WildFly / JBoss](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/installing_oracle_jdbc_driver_on)

Comment: I have done this and datasource is created successfully. But still the error remains the same. I have done debugging of this code. When it reaches the `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")` it skips the further statement and directly gives the "ClassNot FoundException".

Comment: Are you using any building tool (Gradle, Maven, etc.) to package your application?

Comment: No I m not using any building tools.

Comment: That's why then. Your OJDBC JAR isn't binded to your classpath therefore, even though you have it as a module on your JBoss installation, your JAR isn't aware that that module should be used. Why don't you try to convert your project into [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/). Perhaps you can use [this](http://theopentutorials.com/post/uncategorized/how-to-create-a-ejb-3-x-project-using-maven-in-eclipse-part-1/) as a starting point.